# Why is Cloud Firestore unable to support queries with multiple whereIn clauses, while MongoDB can use multiple $in operators?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-firestore, mongodb-query

I’m new to data structures, and I’m not too sure how they work. I’m also new to app development, so after some research without avail, I just picked a NoSQL database, Cloud Firestore, simply because Flutter is also by Google.

After building up my social media app, I find that I really want to query my collection of posts, which is stored in Cloud Firestore, with multiple ‘whereIn’ clauses, but that’s apparently not allowed.

Sample data:

```dart
post1: {
  'timestamp': 2022-01-01T18:22:41.030558
  'user': 'user1'
  'gym': 'gym1',
  'grade': 'grade1',
  'colour': 'red',
  'area': 'area1'
}
post2: {
  'timestamp': 2022-01-01T18:23:41.030558
  'user': 'user2'
  'gym': 'gym1',
  'grade': 'grade1',
  'colour': 'red',
  'area': 'area1'
}
post3: {
  'timestamp': 2022-01-01T18:23:42.030558
  'user': 'user2'
  'gym': 'gym3',
  'grade': 'grade3',
  'colour': 'black',
  'area': 'area3'
}
```

Sample query which should return only `post2` (doesn't work, obviously) (in my actual app, I want to get 10 posts at a time):

```dart
final query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')
  .orderBy('timestamp')
  .startAfterDocument(lastDoc)
  .where('user', isNotEqualTo: 'user1')
  .where('gym', whereIn: ['gym1','gym2','gym3'])
  .where('grade', whereIn: ['grade1','grade2','grade3'])
  .where('colour', whereIn: ['red','blue','green'])
  .where('area', whereIn: ['area1','area2','area3'])
  .limit(10)
```

I also found out that MongoDB, however, can do this. Why is that so? And is this a legitimate reason to switch to MongoDB, or is this just a trivial issue that is usually worked around? Thanks.

Comment: Both are different databases and may have their own pros and cons. If you could share a screenshot of your database structure then it'll be easier to check if there's any work around.

Comment: @Dharmaraj okay, I've edited my post

Comment: @Prabir my apologies, I’ve been unable to access my computer for the past week or so and will continue to be unable to for another week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) in Cloud Firestore,  it supports at most one `in` clause per query.

> You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine in , not-in, and array-contains-any in the same query.

This limitation is by design to enable scalable operations with low response times. To achieve this, all results should be served by the index and require minimal processing time. Nested conditional queries utilize processing time which results in slower responses. The nested queries are good for low volume queries in NoSQL databases, however when scaled to millions of queries per second, can introduce severe performance implications.

You can use multiple queries or you can implement the filter logic inside the code to get the desired result after getting the data from Cloud Firestore.

Comment: would you say then that i should use mongoDB if i don't expect to ever require millions of queries per second?